# Why does Firefox seem to have an `innerHTML` property on jQuery objects, but Chrome requires `.get(0)`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #main{
            color: red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='try'>
<h1 id='main' style='color: green'>hello</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can try to get the text inside the div by doing:

```
$('.try').innerHTML
```

and this will return the value I expect when using Firefox.
However, if I try to run the same thing on Google Chrome, I am told that this is undefined. To do the same thing on Chrome I must do.

```
$('.try').get(0).innerHTML
```

Can anyone explain how this is being evaluated differently in each Browser, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Use `.text()` or `.html()`  instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Please go through and select answers to your previous questions by clicking the empty check mark next to the correct answer. Please do this before asking any more questions.

Comment: See [Web Console Helpers](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is a pure html dom function. When using `jQuery`, use:

- `$('.try').html()`

or

- `$('.try').text()`

Answer (score 3):

This will retrieve the HTML inside the "try" elemented class (hello):

```
$('.try').html()
```

But this will retrieve only the text (hello):

```
$('.try').text()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr:

The sample code mixes jQuery techniques with native javascript properties.

#### jQuery's $():

`$('.try')` will:

> Return a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or created by passing an HTML string. <sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)</sup>.

Thus the return value of `$('.try')` is a collection, which typically wouldn't have a property *innerHTML*<sup>†</sup> (like an element would).

As has been mentioned by others, browsers can define a function for $() however they choose. It may or may not return values similar to jQuery's [$() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

As @Kind user suggested in comments, use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.<sup>[2](http://api.jquery.com/text/)</sup>

So to use jQuery:

```
$('.try').text()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
  console.log('first element with class "try" text: ',$('.try').text());
});
```

```css
#main{
            color: red
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='try'>
<h1 id='main' style='color: green'>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Or with native javascript (using [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) can be used:

```
var tryElements = document.getElementsByClassName('try');
if (tryElements.length) {
    tryElements[0].textContent;
 }
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(readyEvent) {
  var tryElements = document.getElementsByClassName('try');
    if (tryElements.length) {
        console.log('first element with class "try" text: ',tryElements[0].textContent);
     }
});
```

```css
#main{
            color: red
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='try'>
<h1 id='main' style='color: green'>hello</h1>
</div>
```

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Though it would be possible to add it to the collection prototype...</sub>

<sup>1</sup>http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

<sup>2</sup>http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Chrome developer tools both implement a function called `$` which can conflict with jQuery. You probably have the developer tools open in one browser but not in another.

`.innerHTML` is a raw DOM accessor. You probably want to stay in jQuery land, and use `$('.try').html()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have stick to either JQuery or pure Javascript, Because for class selectors you used JQuery ( **$('.try')** ) and access the value inside dev you used pure javascript (**innerHTML**).

So you can use like this to access the html inside the div

```
var element = $('.try').[0] || $('.try');
var value = element.innerHTML;
```

or else directly use JQuery method, library will handle browser issue.

```
$('.try').html();
```